# how can pass array to java servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp, servlets

On my jsp, this is my code :

```
 $('.save').on("click",function(){    
    var array = $.map($('table tr'), function (val, i) {
            var obj = {}, inputs = $(val).find('td input:not(:hidden)');
            obj[inputs.filter(':first').val()] = $.map(inputs.not(':first'), function (val, i) {
                return val.value;
            });
            return obj;
        });
        var data = JSON.stringify(array);
        $.post("Controller.html", data, function(response) {
        /// i dont know what to put here,so i think this where i get trouble with
     });
    });
```

but still data is null when i check on servlet.

this is my servlet :

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String data=request.getParameter("data");
        if (data== null) {
            System.out.println("null");
        }
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/page.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kP9y/7/) here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to send the data, you can use an [ajax post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method:

```
$.post("yourservlet", data=JSON.stringify(array), function(response) {
    // handle response from your servlet.
    alert(response)
});
```

In servlet, you retrieve the data with the command:

```
String data=request.getParameter("data");
```

Then you need to parse the json, you can use a library like JSON simple:

```
Object obj = JSONValue.parse(data);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
```

Or you can manually parse it. Based on your code, your json string will look like this:

```
data = "[{'orange':['1.00','5']},{'apple':['2.00','5']}]";
```

You can use split() method or StringTokenizer to separate each object, but you should write your own parser method, for this you can find many tutorials on google.

Comment: can i add this on my jsp file? with no included library? i am new to json and ajax tech

Comment: In the server-side, you have a string of data which sent from client. Then you must seperate it to meaning data, it's called parse. And manual parse means you do it yourselft without using any JSON libraries.

Comment: thanks, can you give me simple example on how to do it without JSON libraries...please.......

Comment: I get the split thing, but why my data is still null? see updated post please.

Comment: @Niang is the controller being called? try `data:data` as the ajax's message

Comment: i dont know what the syntax, im new to ajax,can you give me some example?

Comment: @Niang I did gave you an example, check it again

Comment: I see that you're posting the ajax request to "Controller.html", is this your servlet? Are you getting that printline of "null"?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin, yes ,when i click the .save, it still null sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58368/discussion-between-alexandru-severin-and-niang).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is in client-side. And java servlet is for server-side.

You must use ajax to make a call from client-side to your servlet.

Comment: I believe that this tutorial is a good start for you: http://hmkcode.com/java-servlet-send-receive-json-using-jquery-ajax/